# user control controling containing form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, recursion

I am using vb.net winforms to create an application which contains a user control, I am also authoring the user control.

The user control is named activate1

The form containing the usercontrol (and other content) is named form1

currently I am trying to enable a button on form1 when a maskedtextbox on activate1 is completed

I attempted to do this by:

```
Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.TextChanged
    If MaskedTextBox1.Text.Count = 34 Then
        Form1.SimpleButton1.Enabled = True
    Else
        Form1.SimpleButton1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

however I receive an error when running the application "The form referred to itself during construction from a default instance, which led to infinite recursion" so instead I tried

```
Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.TextChanged
    If MaskedTextBox1.Text.Count = 34 Then
        me.SimpleButton1.Enabled = True
    Else
        me.SimpleButton1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

however this flags and does not allow compiling as I am referring to a button that does not exist in the user control

How can I accomplish this

Comment: You can add a RT property on the UserControl which allows you to pass the form reference, or perhaps try .FindForm on the usercontrol.  In general, it sounds like some of this would be better served by a class.

Comment: I chose usercontrol based off the recommendations of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191450/making-multiple-forms-appear-as-one-in-vb-net

Comment: can you explain the syntax of findform as I tried Dim myform As Form = Form1.SimpleButton1.FindForm() and it does not seem to work and everything else sets the syntax flag off

Comment: you would do that from inside the Usercontrol:  `frm = Me.FindForm`.  then the UC could reference form controls: `frm.Button1.Enabled`.  It might be better to set UC props for a button reference than assuming it will be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the 1st error is that you use the type name to refer to Form1 where you'd need the concrete instance of the parent form. You can access the parent form by accessing the [ParentForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-property:

```
Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim form = TryCast(ParentForm, Form1)
    If form IsNot Nothing Then
        If MaskedTextBox1.Text.Count = 34 Then
            form.SimpleButton1.Enabled = True
        Else
            form.SimpleButton1.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Please note that this approach couples your Form and your UserControl tightly. Though it will work, it reduces the reusability of your UserControl (in fact, you can only use it on Form1 and not on other forms). Though you can improve this, e.g. by creating an interface, but the UserControl will always by tied to the forms that support this button in one way or the other.
A more reusable approach would be to raise an event in your UserControl and handle this in the parent form, e.g.:

```
Public Class ActivationInfoEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Property Completed As Boolean
End Class

Public Event ActivationInfoChanged As EventHandler(Of ActivationInfoEventArgs)

Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim completed As Boolean
    If MaskedTextBox1.Text.Count = 34 Then
        completed = True
    Else
        completed = False
    End If
    RaiseEvent ActivationInfoChanged(Me, New ActivationInfoEventArgs() With { .Completed = completed })
End Sub
```

You add a handler for the event in Form1 and (de-) activate the button in this handler. This way, you can use the UserControl on a wider variety of Forms.

Comment: the top option raised: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsApplication19.exe but was not handled in user code

the bottom option made the application unstable and I had to revert to an old version just to get designer working again

Comment: @JamesStafford: I've updated the sample so that it should also work in the designer. Obviously ParentForm is not set at design time.