# Parent form and child User Control communication in WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms

I have my form with a menu bar and space underneath to display my controls. One of the buttons in my menu bar is suppose to be a print button that prints a graph that's currently in a User Control I display in the form. If the graph was on the form in the print button's eventhandler I could just simply call

```
graph.printing.print(true)
```

which isn't going to work in my case since the graph is in the control and not the form.

How do I communicate with a User Control from the containing form and access or pass its variables when needed? I also have a status bar on the bottom of the form which would also need to get updated from the User Control, but I'll be able to deal with that if I got help with just this one part. Please bear in mind, I also have another User Control I'm going to add to the form which will also contain a graph which will need the same treatment as the other graph on the first control when the print button is pressed. I plan on swapping these two out so I have one form displaying one control at a time.

I got this idea from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18191630/2567273 but after further research I can't find anyone asking about the actual communication process between a form and the control it contains.

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7382220/2567273) is close to what I'm looking for, but I think it's leading me down the path to using panels instead of User Controls.

After typing this I noticed the closest answer to my question may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21660619/2567273), but that question has the child raising events and the parent responding while I have the parent raising the event and the parent has to get information from the child.

Comment: whatever the form needs from the UC should be made available via properties or methods.  When the user clicks print, the form gets this and that from the control and prints it **OR** since it is apparently data managed by the usercontrol, just expose a PrintGraph method on the UC which the form invokes

Comment: Then if you had another UC, which also had a graph you could print, you would just have to use the same methods or properties to achieve it. Right?

Comment: Yes - there is a reason you have these user controls: (theoretically) they are built as specialists in managing and displaying foobars.  Print is just one of the related operations.  Offloading to the form can work, but the can be A LOT of stuff to pass back for something else to print/process/save/upload....  Since the Form is host to the menu, his role CAN be as little as getting the command  and passing it along to the relevant actor.  Just because the form does have the menu is not a good reason for it to take on printing.

Comment: That would also make the UC more modular since it wouldn't be giving anything out if I made it so only my UC performed the related operation like printing or anything else I'd have to do. If you turned your comment into an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to think about this is *Roles*.  Presumably you built this UserControl to handle the management of the data related to the graphs.  As such you can think of them in the Role of a Graphs Specialist .  Once you do that, printing them is actually just one more thing it should perhaps do.

The form on the other hand, is not special just because it happens to get receive the command from the user to print.  Its role in this might simply to be to know which usercontrol to contact and which method to invoke:

```
 Sub PrintGraphMenuClick....

     Select Case something        ' determinant as to which UC to contact
         Case operation.Foo
             ucFoo.PrintGraph

         Case operation.Bar
             ucBar.PrintGraph
```

Other menu options like `Clear`, `NewGraph`, `Save` and whatever else there is somewhat the same way. The Form's Role here may be to receive the command from the user and pass it along to the right control, invoking the correct right method and passing the correct parameters - that is not a trivial task.

Of course, rather than a `MainMenu`, the usercontols could alternatively implement a `ContextMenu` and even receive those commands directly.

Very often offloading an operation to something else results in so many properties, filenames, streams etc having to be moved from here to there that it becomes burdensome.  In this case it is not like the MainForm has some special ability regarding printers that the UserControl cannot handle.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on your comment! I know what to do now. I'll also keep that ContextMenu idea in mind. Not to keen about the double negative though.

Comment: that was originally for emphasis, but that was also sort of hurried.  Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

There is only one right solution:

1) Add an event to your user control.

2) Raise the event when the particular "thing" happens in the user control.

3) Attach a handler to the event in Form code.

4) Add code to update the bottom bar in the event handler.

Comment: That's the perfect solution I was hoping for when it comes to updating the status bar. Thank you. Sadly, my question is asking how do you make the form talk to and get "stuff" out of the control and be loosely coupled since I'm going to have multiple controls.

Comment: Please elaborate "talk to" and "stuff"

Comment: (All this can be found in my question btws) In my form I have a menu bar. One of the menu items is print which is to print a graph that is found in the control which is inside the form. How do I pass the graph from the control up to the form to be printed?

Comment: why does the form need to be the one to print something else's data?  and by "print" do you mean on a printer or to some other control? @user2567273

Comment: Why not just add public getter property exposing the data you want to expose?

Comment: "Print" as in printer. Because of SOC. The form is a menu bar, a status bar, and there's a spot for the controls. You display the controls and any of the control's events are handled inside the control. The form is the control's parent and should be able to access the parts of the control that are public. What's wrong with that logic?